# Ajax loading dynamic content in new tab - Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am currently building a single page app.  The main index.html file contains one div tag and uses JavaScript to load all content as you navigate through the site.  I've noticed with Google Chrome if you right-click on a link and choose to open in a new tab the content of the page does not load until you click on the tab to make it active.  In FireFox and Internet Explorer the content loads as soon as the new tab opens.

Are there any solutions to have the content load in Google Chrome when the tab opens before it becomes the active tab?

Comment: Does not happen in my chrome. Content gets loaded as soon as the new tab is open.

Comment: Does the page you are opening contain content in the HTML code?  The new page I am opening only has a single div tag and relies on JavaScript to populate the content of the page.  This JavaScript does not execute until I click on the new tab.

Comment: Yes, it does have all the content. The workaround I used for test is a page that relies on ajax call to populate the content and it gets loaded before I click the tab

Comment: Thanks @aarryy.  I must not have been patient enough.  This link shows a sample app with the same experience.  If you right-click on one of the links in the top black bar and open in a new tab, then watch the new tab's title bar until it changes.  It eventually does change I wasn't waiting long enough.  With other browsers it changes almost immediately.